# How to set global values for daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Github: [Bootstrap Daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker), plugin source: [daterangepicker.js](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/blob/master/daterangepicker.js)

I want to set global values for the `locale` option. I don't want to set it for each element every time I use it.

Here is an example code how to setup daterangepicker for a specific element.

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "weekLabel": "W",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Su",
            "Mo",
            "Tu",
            "We",
            "Th",
            "Fr",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },
    "startDate": "12/01/2016",
    "endDate": "12/07/2016"
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});
```

Is it even possible? Or do I have to rewrite the plugin?

What's the best approach if this is not possible without some custom modification?

Comment: Those look a lot like the default options; are you sure you need to include that every time?

Comment: Every time I need an element with the `daterangerpicker` applied to it I have to add these settings (and even more). I might be missing something, that's why I asked the question

Comment: Well, I was just looking at the "configuration generator" and it seems to work the same way whether that locale node is there or not. You might have some other code that's interfering.

Comment: Are you are saying if I apply these settings to one element they are applied to every other element (completely independent from this element) too?

Comment: No, I'm saying you don't have to have them there for any element, at least according to the demo.

Comment: Of course it works without applying these settings. But I want these settings. Except I don't want to specify them every time I use `daterangepicker`

Answer (score 1):

Dan Grossman added support in [2.1.26](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/releases/tag/v2.1.26)

```
Added support for $.fn.daterangepicker.defaultOptions to set default options for all pickers on page.
```

Lets try to explain it here for newcomers.

```js
$.fn.daterangepicker.defaultOptions = {
    locale: {
        "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
        "fromLabel": "Desde",
        "toLabel": "Hasta",
        "customRangeLabel": "Personalizado",
        "weekLabel": "W",
        "firstDay": 0,
        "daysOfWeek": ["Lu","Ma","Mi","Ju","Vi","Sa","Do"],
        "monthNames": [
            "Enero",
            "Febrero",
            "Marzo",
            "Abril",
            "Mayo",
            "Junio",
            "Julio",
            "Agosto",
            "Septiembre",
            "Octubre",
            "Noviembre",
            "Diciembre",
        ]
    }
}

$('#period').daterangepicker();
```

Thanks to @kurdemol94

Answer (score 0):

you can store the `dateRangePickerSettings` as a global variable

```
var dateRangePickerSettings = {
    locale: {...},
};
```

and reference it to all ur plugin instances

```
$('#demo1').daterangepicker({
    "locale": dateRangePickerSettings.locale,
    "startDate": "06/01/2016",
    "endDate": "06/07/2016"
});

$('#demo2').daterangepicker({
    "locale": dateRangePickerSettings.locale,
    "startDate": "12/01/2016",
    "endDate": "12/07/2016"
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I have to do if the plugin does not provide any way to set global options.

Comment: I did (but does not show because I have not enough reputation). However it seems like there is no _right_ solution? :(

Comment: There is some discussion here about having default options but no solution yet: https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/1276

Comment: @alexkb just FYI author replied in the issue, it seems to be possible now. It's not documented and I haven't tested it personally